# Why do swipeActions not work on a sidebar style list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-swipeactions

I'm trying to add SwipeActions to a List in SwiftUI. It is working as expected, but as soon as i give the list the `.sidebar` listStyle it stops working. Here is a minimal code example showing this problem (can be used in Swift Playgrounds):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    let strings = ["hello", "there"]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(strings, id: \.self) { str in
            Text(str)
                .swipeActions {
                    Button { print("clicked on swipe action") } label: { Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash") }
                }
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar) // <-- without applying this, the swipeActions work.
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

I searched Google and Stackoverflow but did not find any answers. It seems very unintuitive that different "styles" also have different behaviour. Am i missing something? Wrapping the `Text` in a `ForEach` loop does not change anything either.

Comment: The problem maybe in Playgrounds, as it works well for me on real ios-15 devices and macos 12 Catalyst using Xcode 13.2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i used it however in an app deployed on macOS 12 and it does not work on that either with the same problem. I just extracted the relevant part for playgrounds, but the issue is the same in my larger codebase. If anyone thinks that is relevant i'd be happy to post more code.

Comment: If you want to use it in a macos 12 only environment, place the `.listStyle(.sidebar)` 
inside the `List`, just after the `.swipeActions`. Seems to work for me.

Comment: The swipe actions then work, however the listStyle is then not applied. As i said, not applying any listStyle resolves the problem, but i would like the list to be translucent and the .sidebar listStyle seems to be the only way of doing that

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with `.sidebar` style as of macOS 13, works with eg. `.inset` style.